# Accessing Parallel Port Using C++

Tags: c++, port, x86-16, parallel-port

I'm tasked to use a DB25 parallel port to take in a digital 8-bit result from an ADC and process it into a signal which can be displayed by Seven Segment Displays using emu8086. I'm also needed to use User Port to access the real parallel port. After taking in digital 8-bit from ADC, the process will be continued using emu8086, then outputs to a decoder then to the Seven Segment Displays.

I've tried plugging the parallel port into my desktop, which then connects to a circuit of simple LEDs and resistors. At the moment I connected them, all 8 LEDs lit up. Why is it so?

It seemed I can't control the circuit hardware just by using User Port and emu8086 through a parallel port.

I've looked up some sites saying that in order to connect the real parallel port to the virtual port of emu8086, I'm required to involve C++. I had some C++ basics with me, but I can't figure a way or codes to connect the parallel port to my emu8086, I've searched a few sites but I don't understand the purpose of the codes.

Can anyone kindly show me some sample codes on how to connect my User Port and emu8086 using C++?

Thank you.

Comment: The parallel port is unknown to C++11 language standard. You need some operating system specific (or hardware specific) function to access it. On Linux you might try to use `/dev/lp`

Comment: Which are those sites? And what do you mean with User Port?

Comment: And do you have a link to emu8086?

Comment: Accessing the parallel port in the manner you describe is quite difficult in modern OS's, because the OS will "own" the port and think that it's a connection to a printer. So, you need to first turn that off, then install a kernel driver that can access the port directly and give you individual results.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What would you recommend for Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: I don't know Windows, and I would recommend using Linux.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: The question here is 16-bit in an emulated environment. It has nothing to do with CreateFile. I claim that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Here's the link to User Port: https://code.google.com/p/unianalyzer/downloads/detail?name=UserPort.zip&can=2&q=
It basically opens the door for me to access parallel port using software in my desktop.
And for emu8086: http://8086-microprocessor-emulator.soft32.com/
There are a few more free downloads using Google Search

Comment: @JohnZwinck The question was regarding controlling LEDs directly using C++. I just need to connect my parallel port to my emu8086 using C++. The controlling part is done by emu8086. I would be happy to accept any ideas if you have any.

Comment: @Callister: I would suggest writing some code, see how far you can get, and come back here with concrete code showing your remaining issues when you get to that point.  As it stands there's not a lot anyone can do with this question that wasn't already addressed in the one I marked this a duplicate of.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: It may happen that emu8086 has some API for mapping the a virtual port to a physical port.

Comment: @MatsPetersson It truly is difficult to access the parallel port. What do you mean by "turn that off"? And do you have any suggestions regarding the kernel drivers?

Comment: @Callister: After looking at how emu8086 works, i have found that it uses a file for I/O.  So what you need to do is to write a program that transfers data between the emu8086 I/O files and the physical port (see refered question). Beside actually accessing the port, you may get trouble with synchronization. If the question was open, I would have posted this as an answer.

Comment: @user877329 Oh, I see how it goes. Thanks.